# simplest mergesort implementation in Python, having type troubles

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I wrote a simple mergesort implementation for learning purpose, but it doesen't work. Even if I go through the code step by step, I don't know why the type problem arises. Here is my code:

```
def mergesort(seq):
    if len(seq)<2:
        return seq
    else:
        m = len(seq)//2
        return merge(mergesort(seq[:m]), mergesort(seq[m:]))

def merge(low, high):
    res = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i<len(low) and j<len(high):
        if low[i] <= high[j]:
            res.append(low[i])
            i = i+1
        else:
            res.append(high[j])
            j = j+1
    res.append(low[i:])
    res.append(high[j:])
    return res
```

and this is what the python-shell returns:

```
>>> mergesort([5,8,1,3,99,5,2,3,4,9,7,5,8])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    mergesort([5,8,1,3,99,5,2,3,4,9,7,5,8])
  File "D:\Documents\alp2\py2.py", line 6, in mergesort
    return merge(mergesort(seq[:m]), mergesort(seq[m:]))
  File "D:\Documents\alp2\py2.py", line 6, in mergesort
    return merge(mergesort(seq[:m]), mergesort(seq[m:]))
  File "D:\Documents\alp2\py2.py", line 6, in mergesort
    return merge(mergesort(seq[:m]), mergesort(seq[m:]))
  File "D:\Documents\alp2\py2.py", line 12, in merge
    if low[i] <= high[j]:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= list()
>>>
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code? Show us how you're using these functions and creating the lists that you pass to them. Anand's answer below is spot-on: you need to use `extend()`. But since the append happens *after* the loop, I suspect you're merging two lists, then merging that output with a third list. Is that correct?

Comment: @skrrgwasme: Actually I have no wider context for this function, I just wrote this mergesort implemetation (along with other sorting functions) for the purpose of learning the different ways to sort things. Yes, if I understand ur question correctly, `merge(seq)` is recursivly called in the process of sorting a list, depending on the length of the list u originally passed to `mergesort(seq)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is mainly because of the lines -

```
res.append(low[i:])
res.append(high[j:])
```

Here, the slicing returns `list`s , and then you are appending those returned lists into `res` list, and returning this `res` list. Hence at sometime, it tries to compare the above added `list` with an integer causing the issue you are seeing.

To add the elements from the list as elements of the `res` list. You should use `list.extend()` instead of `.append()` . Example -

```
res.extend(low[i:])
res.extend(high[j:])
```

---

Demo -

```
>>> def mergesort(seq):
...     if len(seq)<2:
...         return seq
...     else:
...         m = len(seq)//2
...         return merge(mergesort(seq[:m]), mergesort(seq[m:]))
...
>>> def merge(low, high):
...     res = []
...     i, j = 0, 0
...     while i<len(low) and j<len(high):
...         if low[i] <= high[j]:
...             res.append(low[i])
...             i = i+1
...         else:
...             res.append(high[j])
...             j = j+1
...     res.extend(low[i:])
...     res.extend(high[j:])
...     return res
...
>>>
>>> mergesort([10,12,55,22,100])
[10, 12, 22, 55, 100]
>>> mergesort(list(range(100,50,-10)))
[60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. I could use `list.extend()` as u showed or alternatively:
`res = res + low[i:]`;
`res = res + high[j:]`

Comment: yea correct, but please note `res + <blah>` is not inplace (though that does not matter for your mergesort implementation).